# Obtaining the stack trace of a segment fault in visual c++ (release build)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

With gcc in linux I am able to add a handler for a crash (e.g. a SIGSEGV) and write the stack trace to a log like so

```
signal(SIGSEGV, signalHandler); // Register for SIGSEGV
...
void signalHandler(int signal)
{
  void* addrBuffer[100];
  backtrace(addrBuffer, 100);
  // print addresses to log
  exit(1);
}
```

Then with the addr2line function I can get a human readable stack trace.

The advantages of this method are

```
- works on release builds with no symbols/debug info
- works on end user/production installs
```

So assuming I can get the log file, I can debug user crashes.

Is there a way to do something similar in Windows with Visual c++?

Comment: Probably there is a better answer by now, still check http://stackoverflow.com/a/446802/1477064

Comment: Try [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx) or [_set_se_translator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx)